# Can we open keynum or keyboard on the bottom sheet or pop up for mobile application?

Tags: forms, input, keypad

I am working on a mobile application. It is like ordering app for grocery but in wholesale and not in retailer. So user can order 100kg to 1,00,000kg for selling purpose. Order range is huge and because of that need UX help.

User can order from range 50kg to 1,00,000 kg. user is selecting quantity as a bag which contains 50kg. But if I am giving the ability to add items with below design then it will be very difficult to add 20-100 bags since the user will have to click 20 times.

[image]

I have decided to give text but not sure if this is already in the bottom sheet mode can I open the keyboard or kyenum to enter a specific value?
Need help for Ux designing.

More - I have redesigned the pop-up but this is a little complex as per below image.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I allow the user to select an amount of product by either volume or quantity?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/how-can-i-allow-the-user-to-select-an-amount-of-product-by-either-volume-or-quan)

Comment: @maxathousand Actually here I am asking in a generic way can we open keynum or keypad if mobile is already having a state where pop up or bottom sheet is present

Answer (score 1):

Let the user type it with a keyboard predefined as a numpad.

Look at how alibaba.com does it in their app :)

[image]

Comment: could you expand on this a little?